# Linq UNION ALL on same DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, union-all

I need to do a union on 3 sets of fields that repeat, I need to join them all into a single result going from:

```
ID1  | NAME1  |   DESC1  |   ID2  |   NAME2  |   DESC2  |   ID3  |   NAME3  |   DESC3
```

To:

```
ID  |  NAME | DESC
```

The data is in a C# DataTable, how can you do a UNION ALL like done in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) to build an array with 3 items for each record:

```
table.SelectMany(row => new []
{
    new { ID = row.ID1, NAME = row.NAME1, DESC = row.DESC1 },
    new { ID = row.ID2, NAME = row.NAME2, DESC = row.DESC2 },
    new { ID = row.ID3, NAME = row.NAME3, DESC = row.DESC3 }
});
```

Comment: While the other methods proposed may work, this is the simplest way to do it with a DataTable as the incoming DataType

Comment: How you will initialize new DataRow objects without explicitly mentioning DataTable object (example: dt.NewRow()). @Alan could you explain how will you use the answer example in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have these classes:

```
public class Row
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string DESC { get; set; }
}
public class ComplexRow
{
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
    public string NAME1 { get; set; }
    public string DESC1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public string NAME2 { get; set; }
    public string DESC2 { get; set; }
    public int ID3 { get; set; }
    public string NAME3 { get; set; }
    public string DESC3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can do something like:

```
var data = new List<ComplexRow>();
var res = data.Select(x => new List<Row>  {
    new Row{ ID=x.ID1, NAME=x.NAME1,DESC=x.DESC1 },
    new Row{ ID=x.ID2, NAME=x.NAME2,DESC=x.DESC2 },
    new Row{ ID=x.ID3, NAME=x.NAME3,DESC=x.DESC3 },
        })
        .SelectMany(x=>x)
        .ToList();
```

And if you only need distinct *row*s you can use *Distinct()*

Answer (score 0):

`Concat` in `LINQ` is equivalent of UNION ALL in SQL.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID1", typeof(int)));

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID2", typeof(int)));


DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
[0] = 1;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row[0] = 2;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row[0] = 3;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row[1] = 1;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row[1] = 4;
dt.Rows.Add(row);


var tbl1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(t => !t.IsNull("ID1")).CopyToDataTable();
tbl1.Columns.Remove("ID2");
tbl1.Columns["ID1"].ColumnName = "ID";

var tbl2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(t => !t.IsNull("ID2")).CopyToDataTable();
tbl2.Columns.Remove("ID1");
tbl2.Columns["ID2"].ColumnName = "ID";

var query = tbl1.AsEnumerable().Concat(tbl2.AsEnumerable());
```